# how winrm can be enabled using psexec from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a wrote a powershell script to do some OS validation remotely.But when the remote server in not enabled with winrm I get below message.So how I can force winrm to enable remotely using psexec?

```
**Connecting to remote server xxxxx.us.oim.com failed with the following error message : The WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request.  Make sure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are properly registered.**
```

I have added a command in my powershell script PsExec.exe \$host -s powershell "Enable-PSRemoting -force" (here $host will give the hostname) This is executing and at the same time I am getting below message also.

```
PsExec.exe : Connecting to xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com...
At line:72 char:1
+ PsExec.exe \\$fqdn -s powershell "Enable-PSRemoting -force"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Connecting to xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Starting PSEXESVC service on xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com...Connecting with PsExec service on xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com...Starting powershell on xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com...
powershell exited on xxxxxxxxx.us.oim.com with error code 0
```

Is that possible to create a condition only if "WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request" then run command to enable winrm !
If possible please let me know how ?

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2703-remotely-enable-winrm-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function enableWinRM {

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\temp\computers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {

$result = winrm id -r:$computer 2> $null

if ($lastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "WinRM already enabled on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor green
} else {
    Write-Host "Enabling WinRM on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor red 
    .\pstools\psexec.exe \\$computer -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet

        if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
            .\pstools\psservice.exe \\$computer restart WinRM
            $result  = winrm id -r:$computer 2>$null

            if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {Write-Host "WinRM successfully enabled!" -ForegroundColor green}
            else {exit 1}

       } #end of if

    } #end of else  
} #end of foreach
```

Just call this function in the end of your script and that is it.

Make sure you have pstools in the folder where your script is.

Comment: suppose if pstools are located system32 path, do we need to change the path as   c:\windows\system32\pstools\psexec.exe \\$computer -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet

Comment: You should. In my case, I have put PStools folder i Temp folder, together where my script is and also that computers.txt file. If you have pstools in some other folder, you should use that path.

Comment: Thanks alot Vladmir

Answer (score 0):

Adding a more detailed version of the code Vladimir posted in the past.

Make sure to copy **PsExec.exe** and **PsService.exe** to your relevant path.

```
Function enableWinRM
{
    try
    {
        # Check if the service is up and running by querying WinRM version:
        $result = winrm id -r:$global:compName 2>$null

        # If it's already running and nothing was done - exit with code 0:
        if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) 
        {
            Write-Host "WinRM service is already enabled on $global:compName" -ForegroundColor Green
        }

        # If exit code is 1, means service is not running - try to start WinRM service on remote machine using PsExec.exe:
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Enabling WinRM service on $global:compName..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Start-Process -Filepath ("\\"+$global:compName+"\c$\temp\PsExec.exe") -ArgumentList "\\$global:compName -s /accepteula -nobanner C:\Windows\system32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet" -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

            # Check again if the service is up and running by querying WinRM version:
            $result = winrm id -r:$global:compName 2>$null
            
            # If exit code is still 1 - means service was failed to start on first attempt - try to restart WinRM service on remote machine using PsService.exe:
            if ($LastExitCode -eq 1)
            {
                Write-Host "WinRM service is still not running on $global:compName. trying to restart WinRM a second time..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Process -Filepath ("\\"+$global:compName+"\c$\temp\PsService.exe") -ArgumentList "\\$global:compName /accepteula -nobanner restart WinRM" -NoNewWindow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                
                # Check again if the service is up and running by querying WinRM version:
                $result = winrm id -r:$global:compName 2>$null
                
                # If the service was successfully started on second attempt and nothing was done at this point - exit with code 0:
                if ($LastExitCode -eq 0)
                {
                    Write-Host "WinRM service was successfully started on second attempt on $global:compName!" -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                
                # Exit code is still 1 and the service was failed to start after two attempts:
                else
                {
                    Write-Host "Error: WinRM service was failed to start on $global:compName" -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            } 
            
            # Exit code turned to 0. the service was started successfully on first attempt:
            else
            {
                Write-Host "WinRM service was started successfully on first attempt on $global:compName!" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
    }

    catch{}
}

$list = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Computers List.txt"
foreach ($computer in $list)
{
    enableWinRM
}
```